# How to share xaml code between different windows phone pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls, windows-phone

In my application I want to have following group of controls:

```
<StackPanel Height="110" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="NameTextBox"/>
        <TextBlock Name="NumberTextBox"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Image Name="ProfileImage"/>
</StackPanel>
```

which I want to share across different pages in the project. But here is the problem:

The contents of the `TextBlock`s and `Image` control are being loaded at runtime in the `PageLoad` event. So they have to be loaded every time navigation occurs. I don't want this to happen. I tried putting the controls in a `UserControl`, loading them in the `UserControl`'s `Loaded` event and including the `UserControl` in various pages. But still the `UserControl`'s `Loaded` event fires on every page. Can I have a way in which I can just load it once and every page uses it? Hope I am clear in the question.

Comment: Please be more clear about _why_ you want to avoid the `Loaded` event. What _specific_ problem occurs that you want not to happen? I doubt you'll be able to suppress the inherent behavior of the XAML framework's navigation, but if you can explain what the bigger-picture problem is here, you might get some advice to help with that. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a way that makes it clear and answerable.

Comment: The image is taking some time to load when i navigate across pages which I want to avoid. I want it to be as instant as possible. Nothing else.

Comment: can't  you just try singleton pattern?

Comment: Why not just load the image once? The `Image` control will load an image object on your behalf if you need it to, but you can also just hand it an already-loaded object. In fact, you can retrieve that loaded object from the first page that uses the `UserControl`, and pass that on navigation to the next page(s). Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't say specifically how that would work in your code, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Yeah i can definitely do that. Infact, I loaded the image as a `BitmapImage` in a global object and kept assigning it to image controls on various pages. I just wanted to know if there is another way possible of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider leveraging messaging with parameters to pass around data between your objects.

You can use an [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/decoupled-event-management/).

The idea is to have your user controls subscribe to events that they would like to respond to.

NOTE:

I do this with viewmodels.
However, I think it is a code-smell when adding this code to user-controls that are meant to have general use regardless of the application employing them.

I use the ***Publish Subscribe pattern*** for complicated class-dependencies:

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            CloseComand = new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    MessageBus.Instance.Publish(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, null);
                });
        }
}
```

**Window:**

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
{
    Subscription _subscription = new Subscription();

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _subscription.Subscribe(Messages.REQUEST_DEPLOYMENT_SETTINGS_CLOSED, obj =>
            {
                this.Close();
            });
    }
}
```

You can leverage [Bizmonger.Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) to get the MessageBus.

**MessageBus**

```
public class MessageBus
{
    #region Singleton
    static MessageBus _messageBus = null;
    private MessageBus() { }

    public static MessageBus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_messageBus == null)
            {
                _messageBus = new MessageBus();
            }

            return _messageBus;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _oneTimeObservers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingSubscribers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Observer> _waitingUnsubscribers = new List<Observer>();

    int _publishingCount = 0;
    #endregion

    public void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _observers);
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        Subscribe(message, response, _oneTimeObservers);
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string message, Action<object> response)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Respond == response).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Respond == response));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public int Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList());
        observers.AddRange(_waitingSubscribers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        observers.AddRange(_oneTimeObservers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.ForEach(o => _observers.Remove(o));
        }

        else
        {
            _waitingUnsubscribers.AddRange(observers);
        }

        return observers.Count;
    }

    public void Publish(string message, object payload)
    {
        _publishingCount++;

        Publish(_observers, message, payload);
        Publish(_oneTimeObservers, message, payload);
        Publish(_waitingSubscribers, message, payload);

        _oneTimeObservers.RemoveAll(o => o.Subscription == message);
        _waitingUnsubscribers.Clear();

        _publishingCount--;
    }

    private void Publish(List<Observer> observers, string message, object payload)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var subscribers = observers.Where(o => o.Subscription.ToLower() == message.ToLower());

        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Respond(payload);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Observer> GetObservers(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = new List<Observer>(_observers.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription));
        return observers;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _observers.Clear();
        _oneTimeObservers.Clear();
    }

    #region Helpers
    private void Subscribe(string message, Action<object> response, List<Observer> observers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_publishingCount >= 0);

        var observer = new Observer() { Subscription = message, Respond = response };

        if (_publishingCount == 0)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);
        }
        else
        {
            _waitingSubscribers.Add(observer);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

**Subscription**

```
public class Subscription
{
    #region Members
    List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    #endregion

    public void Unsubscribe(string subscription)
    {
        var observers = _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription);

        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            MessageBus.Instance.Unsubscribe(observer.Subscription, observer.Respond);
        }

        _observerList.Where(o => o.Subscription == subscription).ToList().ForEach(o => _observerList.Remove(o));
    }

    public void Subscribe(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.Subscribe(subscription, response);
        _observerList.Add(new Observer() { Subscription = subscription, Respond = response });
    }

    public void SubscribeFirstPublication(string subscription, Action<object> response)
    {
        MessageBus.Instance.SubscribeFirstPublication(subscription, response);
    }
}
```